# locale_t is undefined in modelicastring.c

Tags: c, locale, modelica, dymola

I got an error while compiling to use dymola model in opal-rt.

```
./ModelicaStrings.c(300): error: identifier "locale_t" is undefined
              locale_t loc = newlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C", NULL);
              ^
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile with `NO_LOCALE` defined. This should avoid the compilation error on OpalRT.